# MVC 4 postback empty viewmodel

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Ok so there are lots of questions regarding this, but I can't seem to get this to work. It should be simple, but I'm left scratching my head.

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(BookingIndexViewModel vm) // Also tried BookingViewModel
{
    return View();
}
```

**Container view model:**

```
public class BookingIndexViewModel
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    public List<BookingViewModel> bookings { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> allAttendances { get; set; }
}
```

**Booking view model** (the VM I'm actually interested in)

```
public class BookingViewModel
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int referralId { get; set; }
    public int attendanceId { get; set; }
}
```

**The View**

```
@model Project.ViewModels.BookingIndexViewModel
@using Project.ViewModels

<fieldset>
    <legend>Registered patients</legend>
    @if (Model.bookings.Count < 1)
    {
        <div>None currently registered</div>
    }
    else
    {
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <span class="display-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.bookings[0].forenames)</span>
            </th>
            <th>
                <span class="display-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.bookings[0].surname)</span>
            </th>
            <th>
                <span class="display-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.bookings[0].dob)</span>
            </th>
            <th>
                <span class="display-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.bookings[0].attendance</span>
            </th>
        </tr>

        @{
            foreach (BookingViewModel b in Model.bookings)
            {
                using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Booking"))
                {
                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.id)
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <span class="display-field">@b.forenames</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span class="display-field">@b.surname</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span class="display-field">@String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", b.dob)</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => b.attendanceStatusId, Model.allAttendances)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            }
        }
    </table>
    }
</fieldset>
```

So the view accepts the container view model `BookingIndexViewModel` and creates a form for each `BookingViewModel` held. When submitted I expect it to pass back the container view model with the modified `BookingViewModel` but it's always empty. I've also tried expecting the single `BookingViewModel` that is modified with the same result. Does MVC submit a hydrated view model of the same type as the type given to the view or the type inferred from within the form block?

The only values of importance that I retrieve from the view is the modified `attendanceId` (that should be filled by the dropdown helper) and the booking id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at a similar question I gave using `for(){}` a try instead of `foreach(){}` and now it works. I expect it has something to do with the mutability of the elements in each type of loop.

Comment: Why the minus? At least have the courtesy to leave a reason.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is almost certainly to do with how you are rendering this

```
foreach (BookingViewModel b in Model.bookings)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.id);
    ...
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => b.attendanceStatusId, Model.allAttendances)
}
```

The HTML for the above is going to look something like

```
<form ... >
<input type="hidden" name="BookingIndexViewModel.id" ... />
<select name="BookingViewModel.attendanceStatusId" ... />
</form>
...
<form ... >
<input type="hidden" name="BookingIndexViewModel.id" ... />
<select name="BookingViewModel.attendanceStatusId" ... />
</form>
...
```

The MVC model binder uses the `name` field to bind data to the destination model, in your scenario you have `BookingIndexViewModel`, what you should find is *at a minimum* your `id` field is populated, but your `List<BookingViewModel>` is definitely going to be empty.

It's not entirely clear what you are trying to do, I suspect that what you want is to display the *entire* booking information but only post an individual `BookingViewModel` back? If that's the case, the following should work

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(BookingViewModel model)
{
    ...
}
```

**View**

```
foreach (BookingViewModel b in Model.bookings)
{
    using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Booking"))
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(b => b.id);
        @Html.HiddenFor(b => b.referralId);
        @Html.DropDownListFor(b => b.attendanceId, Model.allAttendances)
    }
}
```

Comment: Little question, how can you use "b" variable for your HiddenFor tag if it's already defined in the foreach?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion 
    you should know how model binding work in asp.mvc ,here is good link that gives details about asp.mvc model binding 
      http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx
 though article is very long it will  help you out to know how model binding works

along with that you should view you html page to know how yours html controls are given names
by razor helpers  as per you view model in your razor page

Answer (score 0):

There is no "postback" in ASP.NET MVC. It's stateless like HTTP do.
If you want to submit something to server, you must include it in the form.

I don't think it's a good idea to pass the whole list of objects from view model back to server.
You have an `Edit` action. Change it's parameter type to `BookingViewModel`. That will allow you to edit single booking item. Then add something like `@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.referralId)` in your form.

Comment: I understand that MVC is stateless, maybe I used the incorrect term but I have included everything I want in the form. Also, seeing as each `BookingViewModel` has its own form I am not sending the entire list back to the server - check the view.

Comment: Understood. When you submit a form, what field is missing?

Comment: Everything was missing, it would not bind any properties from the submitted data - until I replaced the foreach with a usual for loop!

Answer (score 0):

MVC Doesn't actually submit anything in particular nor does it know about your expected `ViewModel` to be submitted to an Action. It will not repost your `ViewModel` as if it were "viewstate".

Ultimately it just posts whatever input elements are in your html within the form, and the Action method, when called, attempts to extract (using binders) whatever you declared as parameter from the values included in your POST.

In your case it seems you would only submit a hidden **Id** and the **attendanceStatusId**. If you look at the browser's actual network traffic you'll notice that is what is being posted.

Therefore, your Action should expect a different ViewModel with two properties that match those input field names.